# Understanding why same couple seemingly married twice within year

Tags: germany, marriage-records, marriage-practices, kurrent, lutheran-church

I've found the record of the marriage of my 8x great-grandparents.  However, I've actually found *two* different records that both appear to document their marriage, on two different dates.

Hans Friderich Illert was from Mihla, Germany.  His father was Berndardt Illert.

Anna Christina Friderici was from Ifta, Germany.  Her father was Johannes Friderici.  He is listed in different places as the 'pfarrer' or 'pastoris' (German vs Latin, I think) in Ifta.  (Both areas were almost entirely Lutheran.)

First entry, from Mihla:

- 1689 entry #72, marriage dated May 28, 1689
  [image]

Second entry, also from Mihla:

- 1690 entry #93, marriage dated DOM Exaudi 1689.  According to https://kirchenkalender.com/, that would have been May 12, 1689.
  [image]

Also unusually, the marriage appears to have taken place in Mihla.  Both of these entries are from Mihla, and there is no entry in Ifta.  (I presume it is because, had the service taken place in Ifta, the pastor of the marriage service would have also been the father of the bride.)

The first child of the couple is documented as born in Mihla on 31 March 1690.  The next child I've found was born 13 Oct 1694.

Can anyone help understand why there would be two entries for this couple's marriage, and which might be the actual date?

EDITED: Corrected the error in the year for the second entry from 1690 to 1689.  Here are the raw PDFs for the second entry:
[second entry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LkJRFpufiKFdpdBTfRhyN0hRXw8_-Kqk/view?usp=sharing) [header page for that section](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xy0UWDE0E7pEN7INDa2vg78qh6yLitvi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure that these are from a different year? The next couple is also listed twice.  Also the previous one? The second entry seems to be a proclamation record, the first one an actual marriage record. If the second one was also from 1689, the deate would be May 12 for proclamation and May 28 for marriage.

Comment: Please give us more information about where you found these records.  In my experience,  when we have problems understanding records, it is often because we have taken the records out of context and thereby lost valuable information that we could use to understand them.  This is a common failure point; we all do it. If you can learn more about the records, why they were created, when they were created, how they were created, & for what purpose, you may also discover the answer to your questions about them. You are asking us to evaluate records while not giving us the context we need to do so.

Comment: Sorry Jan, I figured that was clear.  Both are from the same church register, only a few pages apart, both in the section of the book for marriage records.  Accessed via archion.de.

Comment: @CuriousM, Let me go take another look.

Comment: @CuriousM, Ok, looks like my notes were incorrect on the second entry, and it is indeed 1689, not 1690, which would answer part of it.  If one is a proclaimation record and the other a marriage record, that might explain it, though I've not seen separate proclaimation records in other area towns' records.  I'll attach the raw pdfs to the question.

Comment: Digging in again, back to the header page for that section of that book, it looks like indeed Mihla did keep a separate section for proclaimations at that time, which would explain what was going on here.  @CuriousM, if you'd like to add an answer here (and in the Emerich question), I'd be happy to mark both as answered.  :)

Comment: similar? https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18371/married-twice-but

Comment: Reminder: Our goal here is not just to answer your question, but to create a repository of worked examples that other users with similar questions can study.   Experienced researchers might know that Lutheran records are likely to be at Archion and Catholic ones at Matricula (IIRC) but a newer researcher might not.  If someone makes a suggestion to improve your question, we're thinking of the larger goal, making it a useful question for others, as well as the immediate one, solving your problem.

Comment: Jan, if I can give some honest feedback without offending, I've been around Stackoverflow for nearly a decade now.  You've left several comments lately, that come off as rather patronizing in their tone, rather than clarifying/expanding upon the question asked.  The question asks what it asks; it did not ask 'Where can I find Lutheran records for Mihla from the 1600s?'.  If it happens to help someone answer that unasked question, that's great.  Your comment came off as formulaic, detached from the context of the question.without serving to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we figured it out in the comments, the second entry is a proclamation record (see the abbreviation *procl*. in the record), the first one an actual marriage record (identified by the word/abbreviation *copul./copuliret*). The correct dates would then be May 12 1689 for proclamation and May 28 1689 for marriage.